# How to display a timeseries in Grafana

Tags: grafana

Currently I'm trying to modify the [SimpleJSON](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource) plugin for Grafana in a way, that it requests data from a REST API that doesn't implement the 4 urls ("/", "/search", "/query", "/annotations") that are required by the original plugin. Also the JSON format differs from the one required by the plugin.

So the basic idea is that I request data from a URL that looks like this: `base?timestamps`. I want to add the base part of the URL as a datasource. And time range will be added to the URL in datasource.js.

However I'm not sure how to properly create the request/graph in the dashboard. After adding the datasource I try creating a new row in the dashboard that contains a graph. When changing the metrics to the datasource with my desired API no data is being displayed.

Also I don't get how I can properly set the time range for the request. The tab time range in the dashboard seems to only apply to whats being displayed but doesn't actually influence the request to my API.

I'm happy about any help. Thanks in advance!

TL;DR How do I display data properly in Grafana when using simple json plugin.

Comment: Have you seen the docs for developing a data source plugin: http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/developing/datasources/ There are examples there of the query and response formats.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation only shows the format of the response. It is unclear to me why the methods `query`, `metricFindQuery`... return `{"$$state":{"status":0}}` and not the actual result of the queries.

Comment: `{"$$state":{"status":0}}` is an unresolved Promise. Nothing to do with the response format - just JavaScript dev. You might be missing a `return` somewhere? Grafana uses the q promise lib: https://github.com/kriskowal/q